# Counter-examples to prove that memoization in dynamic programming is not always helpful

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

This was part of my class test last month and since then I've spent some time reading about Memoization in DP and its influences on the latter. I was able to find and thoroughly understand cases where it proves to be fruitful however since DP fundamentally takes this approach to ***"store"*** the subproblems for later use, doesn't this make the question kinda wrong in the sense that there'll be always some sort of caching of present solutions for future use?

Please correct me if I've mistaken anything.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46285976/1835769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! Memoization is not helpful in every case. One simple counter example one can think of would be the `factorial(n)` function where you need to compute factorial of a given number `n`.

`factorial(n):
if(n = 1) return;
else return n*factorial(n-1);`


Consider the above pseudocode to compute factorial of given number `n`. Say, n = 5, the function will compute `factorial(5)` like this:

- 5*`factorial(4)`
- 4*`factorial(3)`
- 3*`factorial(2)`
- 2*`factorial(1)`
- 1*`factorial(0)`
- 1

As you see, each time a new value is returned from the function and **storing** the value every time doesn't make sense because subsequent recursive calls will not be able to benefit from it.

In cases like these, we follow another approach which we call as **tabulation**.

Comment: I guess you can compute factorial by memoizing as well. Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905766/how-does-memoizing-a-recursive-factorial-function-make-it-more-efficient

Comment: So, figuring out through recursion tree helped in understanding this to a certain extent as to why memoization never really helps in this case as opposed to other cases like computing fibonacci series through memoization.